# How to run a nested for loop for two lists in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, nested

I have two lists that represent data tables in Domo which I am using the Domo API to retrieve:

```
id = list(1,2,3)
tablename = list(a,b,c)
```

I am trying to fetch data via the DomoR::fetch function and name them as dataframes in R. How would i do this? I imagine it is something like this?

```
for(x in id){
  for(y in tablename){
    y = DomoR::fetch(x)
  }
}
```

Without using for loops this is what i would like:

```
a<-DomoR::fetch(1)
b<-DomoR::fetch(2)
c<-DomoR::fetch(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with DomoR but based on comments, and without a reproducible example, I think this is what you need

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
my.names <- c("a","b","c")

tablename <- list()
for(y in 1:length(my.names)){
    tablename[[y]] <-  DomoR::fetch(id[y])
}

names(tablename) <- my.names
```

Now the first element of tablename will contain the elements in table id "1" and so forth. The elements on the `tablename` list are named according to the names of `my.names`.

I made `id` and `my.names` vectors instead of lists for easier syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This resulted in a list of 5 identical dataframes. I would like to the result to be fetching each data table which is identified by their Domo table ID's and naming them with their corresponding names.

In this case table "a" would contain the elements in table id "1" and so forth. Domo just houses the data, I am trying to extract these tables using their ID's.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. Let me modify my answer

Comment: I think this is closer, I just need to maintain the table names for each id. For example "a" = table containing table contents in id 1, "b" = table containing table contents in id 2.

In my head the for loop would read: "for id in table id's and for name in table names: fetch data from table id and name it with the corresponding table name"

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Im sorry, this is not what I am looking for really. The result would ideally be three R dataframes named a, b, and c which contain data tables in Domo which are represented by id's 1, 2, and 3 respectively. i.e. a<-fetch(1), b<-fetch(2), c<-fetch(3). I just want to do this program iteratively